# Why in Partition 'SWITCH' statement source & target must reside in the same filegroup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I know that switching between partitions requires both the partition to reside in same filegroup.But am not able to find any proper place to know **where/what could be the reasons behind that concept**.

**Source and target tables must share the same filegroup.**
The source and the target table of the ALTER TABLE...SWITCH statement must reside in the same filegroup, and their large-value columns must be stored in the same filegroup. Any corresponding indexes, index partitions, or indexed view partitions must also reside in the same filegroup. However, the filegroup can be different from that of the corresponding tables or other corresponding indexes.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx

In one of my partition implementation:

> I keep my archival table in same filegroup, perform SWITCH , then drop
> and recreate clustered index to move data to different filegroup.This is costing me much !

I want the old data moved to different table i.e archivaltable (for analysis purpose) residing in a different filegroup(different drive).But due to this restriction i have implemented as mentioned

I understand the concept followed (data is not physically moved). but why?
Expecting answer such as *"due to sql-server pagesize limitation or paging concept overlaps etc etc"* like that.

Please help me find or understand this !

Comment: As it says on the page you link to "the data is not physically moved"

Comment: I have updated my question with expected answer

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement is that efficient because it's essentially just replacing addresses on-disk instead of moving the data around. Hence, both sets of data need to be in the same file-group in order to facilitate this "trick".

Comment: But if am not wrong the switch we use majorly is to archive old data to other table.is it not that my archival table will reside in another filegroup in another storage area.

Comment: SWITCH could also replace the stored filegroup information for the partitions to switch. It should still be possible.

Comment: @usr please share me a link or explain your comment.I cannot fully understand your comment.

Comment: Why would it be impossible to update the meta data that stores the filegroup information just like SQL Server updates the meta data that stores to B-tree root? In this answer I do not find a reason why switch cannot switch across filegroups.

Comment: @usr - which disk data is stored on isn't metadata that can just be flipped.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following setup

```
     FG1                    FG2
      |                      |
------------            ------------
|          |            |          |
F1         F2           F3         F4
```

Where the `FG`s are file groups and the `F`s below are individual files.

We have a partition whose data, by chance, all happens to currently exist within `F1`. After we've performed the switch, all of its data will still be within `F1`. Despite the restriction only being specified in terms of file groups, the restriction is actually "the data has to stay inside the same file".

Why? Because that's the whole reason we can do this efficiently. We can't take the extents (or even individual data pages) within `F1` and suddenly make them part of `F2` (or `F3` or `F4`) because those other files might be located on other disks. You can't say "this page of this disk here is now part of that file, located over there on another disk" - that's not how (most traditional) file systems work - certainly the ones that SQL Server works on.

And in the case of wanting to move across file groups, you can't suddenly say `F1` (or part of it) is now part of `FG2` as well as, or instead of, it belonging to `FG1`. Files only belong to one file group because [File Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316(v=sql.105).aspx) are the level of management for several features.

If we want to move a set of rows between two tables but we want to write it in a way that doesn't have data movement restrictions, we've already got the tools to do that - `INSERT` and `DELETE` (possibly writing it as one cute combined statement using `OUTPUT` from `DELETE` as the source of rows for the `INSERT`).

Someone at Microsoft could sit down and write an implementation of `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` that does allow data movement to occur - but they haven't seen the need to implement that. Instead, they've documented the current restriction.

---

(I'll note that I'm still not linking to any "official sources" or really adding much new here that can't be gleaned from understanding what filegroups actually are, which I'd hope someone would have at least some familiarity with before they encounter a situation where they're actually trying to move data between them)

Comment: Let's say Table1 is on FG1 and Table2 is empty and on FG2. We now switch Table1 and Table2. Can't we just change the metadata of Table1 to be empty and the metadata of Table2 to be located on FG1? Yes, that would move Table2 to a different FG but that could be OK. (And in these statement I use table and partition interchangeably).

Comment: @usr - except that the actual bytes of actual data are still sitting on disk 1, as part of the `F1` file. It defeats the purpose of *having* separate file groups and being able to control *where* data is placed. I'd hoped I'd addressed that sufficiently above but apparently not.

Comment: My point would be that switch could work in this situation and produce a useful result. Of course, it cannot move the data. But the logical data change could be made to work. Or maybe I'm just not thinking straight here.

Comment: @usr - what useful result? Most of the time, people are *using* separate file groups so that they can make use of separate disks (or channels). So if the data has stayed put on the original disk, you *haven't* achieved the useful result.

Comment: Or, you could use file groups to control fragmentation and backups. Or, it might just be a special situation which could be solved handily with this. The limitation discussed here seems arbitrary because there's no technical reason for it.

Comment: @usr - okay, *if* there was an easy way to ask the OS "please take this set of pages from this one file and attach them into this other file instead" then the restriction *could*, instead, be that the target file group must have at least one file on each disk where data is currently stored, then that could possibly be implemented. How that would work in the presence of e.g. setups where people have configured fixed sizes for files I don't want to try to contemplate. So having a *simple* limitation that actually works with the file system APIs available seems like a good choice to me.

Answer (score 0):

One filegroup could store multiple table's data. The statement refers to a table not to a filegroup. When a filegroup stores multiple table's data and you are trying to move only one table's data (switching only one table to another FG), the original filegroup should be splitted which requires lots of resources to do the operation (to physically move the data). In this case the operation is similar to when you move an index or clustered key to another filegroup.

**Edit** Additionally the source and target FG and the associated partition scheme and function not necessary the same and the data what you are trying to move not necessary fits to the partition definition in the new filegroup.

**From the comments below**

> Why would it be impossible to update the meta data that stores the filegroup information just like SQL Server updates the meta data that stores to B-tree root? In this answer I do not find a reason why switch cannot switch across filegroups.

It is not impossible, but one physical file could not be the part of multiple FGs. If you are changing only the metadata to another FG and the original FG stores multiple table's data (which means a physical file stores multiple table's data) a file split would be necessary, or if the data is not moved, a file will be part of multiple FGs.

Answer (score 0):

The use case for SWITCH is not to relocate data to different storage but to move data into a different table as a meta-data only operation.  This is by design.  There are no technical reasons that prevent SQL Server from moving the partition to a different filegroup but then it would no longer be just meta-data, and the operation could be quite time consuming due to extensive data movement.  This would basically the same costly operation you currently do manually.

This begs the question as to why you are moving the data to a different table at all.  I would think you'd just want to move the partition to a different filegroup but keep it in the original table.

Comment: I want it moved to different table(for analysis purpose) residing in a different filegroup(different drive).But due to this restriction i have implemented as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Why does the archived data need to be different table/filegroup for analysis?  Couldn't the analysis be done with data in the original table with a WHERE clause on the partitioning column?

Comment: It could be done, but there is a different application altogether waiting to dive into this data.What i understand is, if i could move this to different filegroup that makes life easy for managing that data separately.